# FxCop 1.36 is gone

Tags: installation, fxcop

I just wanted to download FxCop 1.36 but I can't find it in the internet.
A few days ago FxCop 10 came out for Windows 7 but I need the old Version.
The file is gone on the MS server and everybody linked it.

Anyone has the old install routine?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I have the 1.36 installer...If you still need it, I could put it up on my Dropbox for you...

Edit: here's the link to the [1.36 installer](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1311259/FxCopSetup_1_36.exe). Enjoy!

Comment: that would be great. thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Go Here

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\FXCop

Comment: You need to install "Windows SDK for Windows 7.1". More details [in this discussion group](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=3541)

Comment: The linked MSDN archive page has gone cold.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be correct. 1.35 is still availble though http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=553

Comment: thanks. that's a start. but I really would like to install the 1.36 version.

Comment: I found this message on msdn:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=3541

Comment: That SDK includes the newest Fxcop, v10.0, not 1.36.

Comment: @Grant - thanks, I should have guessed so. I still wonder why removing the latest version but keeping 1.35.

Answer (score 1):

You can download from here:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=553

Click on **FxCopInstall.exe** link and it will download.

Regards,

Sushil Kumar