# Is there a CIL Static Analysis Library like ASM for Java Bytecode?

Tags: static-analysis, cil, java-bytecode-asm, cci

I am looking for a **library** for doing custom static code analysis on CIL code. READ: I have no interest in a tool that already does static analysis like those shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#.NET).

For custom analysis with Java Bytecodes, I have used ASM and I like the features it offers and the good documentation. 
A quick google search for "CIL static analysis library" doesn't yield anything that seems to provide the features of ASM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) is the best library for CIL analysis available. It is free, open-source, complete, lightweight, robust and fast. In addition to reading CIL, it can also write CIL. It also supports PDB files.

Many static analysis tools rely on Cecil for years.

Comment: Thanks I will look more into this Cecil.

Comment: Cool, you won't find anything better anyway. I am the lead developer of the static analyzer NDepend that relies on Cecil for 5 years, and I can say that the author of Cecil (Jb Evain from SyntaxTree http://syntaxtree.com/) did a great job an provides an awesome support!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Reflector: www.reflector.net/

Comment: This looks more like a tool that internally uses static analysis and not a library for enabling static analysis like ASM.

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing I've found is Microsoft's [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(v=vs.80).aspx) utility. (Standalone download link [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/codeanalysis/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=553), 1.36 seems to have disappeared, but someone [re-uploaded it to their Dropbox on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114939/1122135))

It's certainly nothing close to C/C++ static analysis tools, but then again, C# is a managed language where a lot of the common mistakes that static analysis tools check aren't possible.

Also, there's a [short list on Wikipedia of static analysis tools for .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#.NET), might be worth a peek.

Comment: I am looking for a **library** that best enables me as a programmer to write custom static analysis for CIL, this seems to be a **tool** that uses static analysis to find bugs, etc.